# Entity Framework - inserting record with many to many relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My application was working fine when I had a one to many relationship between my entities but now I have tried to switch it to a many to many and I'm struggling on how to get it to correctly insert.  I think I probably have something not quite right in my models.

Now when I run a context.saveChanges() in my controller, it is failing because of this error: `Failed in 97 ms with error: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Products_dbo.Categories_CategoryID". The conflict occurred in database "database", table "dbo.Categories", column 'ID'. The statement has been terminated.`  I took a look at the query.  I have 3 existing categories with id's of 1, 2, and 3.  Now in my query the CategoryID is 0 but my IEnumerable CategoryIDs has a 1 and 2 in it which is what I want.  How do I proceed to get this to enter the product for both category 1 and 2?

Category Model:

```
public class CategoryModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [Display(Name = "Category Name")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public String categoryName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public String categoryDBName { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(true)]
    [Display(Name = "Active?")]
    public bool isActive { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ProductModel> ProductList { get; set; }

}
```

Product Model:

```
public class ProductModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [Index("ItemNumber", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Item #")]
    public int itemNumber { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [Display(Name = "Product")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public String product { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    [MaxLength(500)]
    public String description { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(true)]
    [Display(Name = "Active?")]
    public bool active { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Image Name")]
    public String imageName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "PDF Name")]
    public String PDFName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Category")]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<int> CategoryIDs { get; set; }

    public virtual CategoryModel Category { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategorySelectList { get; set; }

    public ICollection<CategoryModel> CategoryList { get; set; }

    public virtual BrochureModel Brochure { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> BrochureList { get; set; }

    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> getCategories(int id = 0)
    {
        using (var db = new ProductContext())
        {
            List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
            var categories = db.Categories.ToList();
            foreach (var cat in categories)
            {
                SelectListItem sli = new SelectListItem { Value = cat.ID.ToString(), Text = cat.categoryName };

                if (id > 0 && cat.ID == id)
                {
                    sli.Selected = true;
                }
                list.Add(sli);
            }
            return list;
        }

    }

    public ProductModel()
    {
        active = true;
    }

}
```

And here is the method in the controller that is saving the changes:

```
// POST
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult EditProduct([Bind(Include = "ID,itemNumber,product,description,active,PDFName,imageName,CategoryIDs")] ProductModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (var context = new ProductContext())
            {
                context.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
                if (model.ID == 0)
                {
                    // Since it didn't have a ProductID, we assume this
                    // is a new Product
                    if (model.description == null || model.description.Trim() == "")
                    {
                        model.description = "Our Famous " + model.product;
                    }
                    if (model.imageName == null || model.imageName.Trim() == "")
                    {
                        model.imageName = model.itemNumber + ".jpg";
                    }
                    if (model.PDFName == null || model.PDFName.Trim() == "")
                    {
                        model.PDFName = model.itemNumber + ".pdf";
                    }
                    Session["dropdownID"] = model.CategoryID;
                    context.Products.Add(model);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Since EF doesn't know about this product (it was instantiated by
                    // the ModelBinder and not EF itself, we need to tell EF that the
                    // object exists and that it is a modified copy of an existing row
                    context.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
                }
                context.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("ControlPanel");
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

**Edit:** I forgot to mention that I do have a third table called ProductCategory that has a ProductID and a CategoryID but I do not have a model for that table.

Comment: where is the code in the controller that is creating the items and calling `SaveChanges()`?  Most likely EF thinks you are trying to add a new item instead of updating an existing item, but it's impossible to know without seeing the code you are using.

Comment: Can you post your controllers or something so we know what youre trying to do here? Most likely you need to put the ID in a hidden form field in your view so it doesn't come back in the HttpPost method as zero aka default(int).

Comment: added controller method now

Comment: I think your actual data model is screwed up. You need a third model that links the two together or else you are going to have a bad time. Something like [in this screenshot](http://a397.idata.over-blog.com/4/08/93/35/Images/r3.png).

Comment: @br4d Actually EF can create the mapping table itself.

Comment: Correct, EF did create the "bridge" table for me.

Comment: However, I'm a bit confused why you have a 1 to many AND many to many relation between the products and the categories.

Comment: @Pluc, I'm sure I have something screwed up in my models.  I need it to be a many to many.

Comment: @dmikester1 I think your real problem Its on EF Configurations. Sometimes you have to provide them by your self. And also I see several IEnumerable instead of ICollections maybe that affects too.

Comment: @dmikester1 Start by telling to EF all configurations for each relation in the model and then try regenerate everything. Here also an old link I used sometimes: http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-1-introduction-and-basic-concepts